# PHP object starts with @

Tags: php, xml, object

I'm getting an XML file and converting to array using:

```
$myObject = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xmlUrl));
```

With var_dump I can see the returning object is:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#614 (4) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "77"
    ["parentCategoryId"]=>
    string(4) "6420"
    ["isFinal"]=>
    string(4) "true"
    ["hasOffer"]=>
    string(4) "true"
    ["hasProduct"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
}
```

I need to get the id. I've already tried `$myObject->@attributes`, `$myObject->attributes` and `$myObject->{'@attributes'}` but no success, the `var_dump` always return an empty object.

Comment: Wow it is really duplicated question. I researched before asking, but I was researching for "object starting with special caracter" I did not think it could be something with simplexml

Thank you very much. I was almost one hour in this.

Comment: Do you use twitter ? or teamviewer ?

Comment: Why are you asking this?

Comment: To make a work connection. And probably share a knowledge ?

Comment: I've looked into your recent interactions at stackoverflow. It seems you are only interested to make "networking connections" with females. You are the reason most womem hide themselves under a male nickname. Stop doing this kind of thing. I'm a professional and I demand respect.